# bundles to MainActivity.java

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, bundle

So I have a recycler view in main activity, and as soon as I hit one element I can go to another screen and use bundles to send information (such as the name of the element in the recycler view that was clicked). That all works fine.

Now I am trying to go back to the main activity and send information to the main activity that will be displayed in a Toast

This is part of what I have in the second activity to go back

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                String text1 = "";
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("xyz1",editText.getText().toString());


                Intent returnIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
                returnIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                view.getContext().startActivity(returnIntent);
            }
```

and this is what I have in the main activity to retrieve it inside the oncreate method

```
//Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        //String value = bundle.getString("xyz1");
        //Toast.makeText(this,value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I have it commented because it crashes. My guess is that it crashes because the first time the program is launched, there is no bundle , there is no information coming from the second activity.

I can do this the other way around (from main activity to second activity)

How to go about this?

Comment: Can you show us the crash log?

Comment: @vinnie where do I see that? Sorry, 100% new to Android

Comment: At the bottom of the Android Studio IDE, look for the `Logcat` tab. Once your app crashes and you press "Close app" on your device/emulator, you'll see a dump of the crash data. If it's an exception, it'll usually be in red type.

Comment: If you don't see the Logcat tab at the bottom of the IDE, reveal it by going to `View --> Tool Windows --> Logcat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try performing a null check before accessing the arguments in the bundle.

```
private static final String EXTRA_MY_STRING = "xyz1";

if (getIntent().getExtras() != null)
{
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String value = extras.getString(EXTRA_MY_STRING);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(value))
    {
       // show Toast
    }
}
```

Also, it helps to post the logcat so that we can see the source of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive it in few different ways,

Your FirstActivity (it is not clear what is the name of the activity) you should use it like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
EditText nameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.query_textbox);
intent.putExtra("key", nameText.getText());
startActivity(intent);
```

Here's how I would accomplish the problem. I think it's formatted in the nicest way and is very easily understood by someone else who might be reading your code(Follow good programming format)

Then inside your SecondActivity.class **(I think in your case it should be MainActivity.class)**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if (extras != null) {
        String extraStr = extras.getString("key");
    }else {
        extraStr = "extra not set";
    }
```

if you want to use well formatted code it should be like this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
// Get the extras (if there are any)
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    if (extraStr.containsKey("key")) {
        String extraStr = extras.getString("key");
        // TODO: Do something.
    }
}
```

or can also use the Intent methods to access your extras directly.

```
String extraStr = getIntent().getExtras("key");
```

I'll attach some references to here, If you want they will help you to get an more idea about this. Thanks.

**References** :  http://ausmarton.blogspot.com/2014/01/bundle-containskey-but-returns-null-on.html

https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.os.Bundle/containsKey